# How to get data from a table in the SAP UI?

Tags: javascript, xml, csv, sapui5

I have a table:

```
<Table id="Listing" class="tableList" mode="MultiSelect" items="{path: 'masterData>/contactsList'}">
                <columns>
                    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                        <Text text="{i18n>vendorNum}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                        <Text text="{i18n>recipientType}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                        <Text text="{i18n>supplierName}"/>
                    </Column>
                </columns>

                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <cells>
                            <Text text="{masterData>vendorNum}"/>
                        </cells>
                        <cells>
                            <Text text="{masterData>recipientType}"/>
                        </cells>
                        <cells>
                            <Text text="{masterData>supplierName}"/>
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
```

And i have a method for export data to csv:

```
onExportCSV:function() {

//... then I want to get the data in the form of an object - sContent

            oExport.generate().done(function(sContent) {
                var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + sContent;
                var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                downloadLink.href = uri;
                downloadLink.download = "data.csv";
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
                console.log(sContent);
            }).always(function() {
                this.destroy();
            });
}
```

How do I get the current data in the table for further exports to the csv? At the same time, for this, I am not in any case should not get these data on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can get the table's content:

```js
onPress: function(){
    var aTableRows = sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("Listing")).getItems();
    console.log("Table rows: ",aTableRows);

    for(var i=0; i< aTableRows.length; i++){
        console.log("Row "+(i+1)+" cells: ", aTableRows[i].getCells());
        var aRowCells = aTableRows[i].getCells();
        for(var j=0; j < aTableRows[i].getCells().length; j++){
            console.log("Row "+(i+1)+" cell "+(j+1)+" value: ", aRowCells[j].getText());
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/pulefevava/3/edit?html,output) is a working example, the data is printed to the console.

After that, you can set up this data as you wish.